# system package vs Application Package?

Tags: module, operating-system, software-distribution, software-packaging

Following is the scenario.
I am developing an Open Source modules for an open source application. (for example : magento / wordpress / drupal)

Now, all this application provides inbuilt module installation interface.

Should It be a good solution, that I build a debiab package for each module that I develop and provide it separately for the installation ?

my reason behind such approach is to update number of instance at one go, while updating OS and during regular maintenance.

Is it a feasible solution ? or should I stick to classical structure.

Cheers,
Mike